# Problem using \DeclareLabelalphaTemplate in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to customize my bibliography list. So, I decide to use Biblatex, I visited CTAN page and I tried to compile the code; and I have reported problems with `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate`. I read the manual, and to use this command, it's mandatory to use Biber; I did. But I can't find the cause. I use XeLaTeX in Texpad software.

The code is the same of the CTAN page, also the bib. file, I've just changed the file name.

> ./Example.tex:13: Undefined control sequence.
>   l.13 \DeclareLabelalphaTemplate
>                                  {
>   ./Example.tex:14: Undefined control sequence.
>   l.14   \labelelement
>                       { 
>   ./Example.tex:15: Undefined control sequence.
>   l.15     \field
>                  [final]{shorthand}
>
> ./Example.tex:15: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

Thank you in advance for your helping.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{Untitled.bib}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
  }
}

\begin{document}
Filler text \parencite{morales}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've just mentioned the error text: Undefined control sequence.

Comment: What version of biblatex/Biber are you using? The version of Biber is in the `.blg` file

Comment: I have two files: .tex and .bib. There is no additional files. I'm using Tex Live, and Biblatex is included.

Comment: If during compilation there are those errors, the most probable cause is an outdated version of `biblatex`

Comment: I'm using Tex Live, Biblatex is included.

Comment: *What* version of TeX Live? Moreover, in the `.log` file there should be a line such as `Package: biblatex 2013/11/25 v2.8a`; what's in yours?

Comment: It's 1.01 version. I'm going to find if I need to update. Thanks.

Comment: This is almost certainly because your biblatex version (and probably biber) is out of date. Probably very out of date if it doesn't recognise those macros. Best thing is to update to TeXLive 2013 and then update all packages with the TL updater.

Comment: The code works perfectly here (if I substitute the `\addbibresource{}` for a file on my machine and adjust the cite command accordingly).

Comment: This question is off topic because it is about an outdated version of the software (`biblatex`).